# Analysis service processing option

Tags: ssas

What is the use of process option in Analysis service Database,Cube,Dimension seperately?If we process database alone,it will process the cube and dimensions inside of that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, processing the database will process the cube and dimensions. If it is working well for you, you should continue. You can process the other objects independently for a variety of reasons. Sometimes you want to only process an update for a dimension which does not require a cube process. Or you want to control processing in a specific order if your server can't handle processing in parallel. Maybe you only want to process one cube in a database rather than all cubes in a database, or maybe you want to process a single partition in a cube rather than the entire cube. These other options are there so that you can decide precisely what to process, whether it is a complete process or an update/add/incremental process, and sequencing of processing so that you can manage your hardware resources appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for processing in SSAS.  These exist for the various scenarios - i.e. testing / development, staging, production, etc... In addition to be being to process a particular object, you can also process the selected object(s) in several ways.  These are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx) and include the following methods:
Default, Full, Clear, Data and more.  Also you might note that most, but not all, processing options are exposed in the GUI. Some of the more granular options are only available via XMLA.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337509) a reference to explain different processing tools.